# LyX -- copy images into build directory for LaTeX include tags

Tags: beamer, graphics, lyx

The default `beamer-ornate` template includes an option to put an institution logo at the bottom of every slide,

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{institution-logo}{logofile.png}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{institution-logo}}
```

Unfortuantely, LyX doesn't know to copy `logofile.png` into the build directory (namely, `/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.T___/lyx_tmpbufN/`), and so the build command fails. How do I make it work correctly?

Comment: This question is basically answered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/automatically-locate-included-images

Comment: Try `\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.5cm]{logofile.png}}`  instead. Maybe LyX has problems detecting the PGF image macros.

Comment: @Charles No, it's really not... that's for LaTeX and orthogonal. Path searching is _not_ desired, I want it fully obvious what image should be included.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Scharrer's comment sent me on the right track. The `\logo` command just sets a sub-document to be placed somewhere appropriate. So, you can create a LaTeX text with "\logo{" (Ctrl-L), use Insert > Graphics as regular, and add a closing LaTeX text with "}".

If an editor screenshot jogs memory for LyX users (hopefully UCB will forgive me for any potential copyright issues),

[image: LyX logo include]

Comment: Glad that I could help.