# Defining a standard folder for image resources

Tags: macros

how can I define a command so that in the preamble of my document I can have something like

```
\FigureFolder{name}
```

So that the following two commands will work

```
\newcommand{\FigureCaption}[3]{\begin{figure}[h!]\centering\includegraphics[scale=#1]{FIGURES/\FigureFolder/#2}\caption{#3}\label{#2}\end{figure}}

\newcommand{\FigureNoCaption}[2]{\begin{figure}[h!]\centering\includegraphics[scale=#1]{FIGURES/\FigureFolder/#2}\label{#2}\end{figure}}
```

Basically I want to associate with every of my LaTeX files a separate figure folder (to keep things a bit organised), and specify the name of that folder at the beginning of the document. Of course, I know I could just copy the `\newcommand` codes in the preamble but I prefer to put those commands in a `.sty` file and not have too many things at the top of my document.

Comment: Typically that is called `\graphicspath{{name}}` and then you can *drop* `\FigureFolder` from the file path in `\includegraphics`.

Comment: See [Automatically locate included images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12986/5764).

Comment: Or you can have in the directory that contains your project's files a `Figures` subdirectory that contains only `symbolic links` to the real graphic files — which you store where you please.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please let us know if @Werner's link resolves the issue; if your question is a follow-up, that's ok :) Let us know either way!