# How can I make LaTeX find a graphics file

Tags: includegraphics

For any business correspondence, I use a graphic, aglogo.jpg.  As long as I'm in the directory where it resides, of course latex always finds it.  But, if I'm working in a different directory it's not found.  Is there a way to make latex find aglogo.jpg no matter what directory I'm in?

Comment: Put it in your texmflocal or some other texmf tree used by your system.

Comment: This is similar in nature to placement of your own `.sty` or `.cls`, even though it's an image. As such, it's a duplicate of [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)

Comment: put into your document's preamble `\graphicspath{{/my/path/of/the/image}}`

Comment: I added the line in the preamble: \graphicspath{{/home/johnfg/church/aglogo.jpg}} but still got this error from pdflatex:

Comment: LaTeX Warning: File `aglogo.jpg' not found on input line 136.

Comment: I figured it out with the help/suggestion of Herbert!  I just needed the directory between the braces, not the graphic image name itself.  Tried it from a couple of directories and all seems to be good.  Thanks Herbert!

Comment: @JohnGodfrey: That approach works, but would require you to have that with every file. It's no different than supplying the full path with every image which seems like something you want to avoid (from your original post). Placing the image(s) in your local TeX folder structure makes it available to *all* files without having to specify the location. If your answer is solved by Herbert's suggestion, then a better duplicate is probably [Automatically locate included images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12986/5764).